# Minecraft Forge: My armor textures are not showing up on armor

Tags: minecraft

The game works fine, it just won't load the textures.

```
package theDwainFilms19.SuperSmashBrosMod.item;

import scala.tools.nsc.MainClass;
import theDwainFilms19.SuperSmashBrosMod.SuperSmashBrosMod;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.Entity;

public class ItemmarioArmor extends ItemArmor {
    public ItemmarioArmor(ArmorMaterial armourMaterial, int id, int              placement){
    super(armourMaterial, id, placement);
}
       public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack stack, Entity entity, int     slot, String type) {
        if (stack.getItem().itemID ==     SuperSmashBrosMod.marioHelmet.itemID ||stack.getItem().itemID == SuperSmashBrosMod.marioChestplate.itemID || stack.getItem ().itemID == SuperSmashBrosMod.marioBoots.itemID) {
        return SuperSmashBrosMod.MODID + ":textures/models/armor/mario_layer_1.png";
    }
    if (stack.getItem().itemID == SuperSmashBrosMod.marioLeggings.itemID) {
        return SuperSmashBrosMod.MODID + ":textures/models/armor/mario_layer_2.png";
    }   else {
        return null;
```

I don't have a clue how to fix this, since it doesn't give a error thing, it just ignores the code.

Edit: here is a crash report for when I went to add a proxy
-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_31, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 687494688 bytes (655 MB) / 1037959168 bytes (989 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.85.1291 Minecraft Forge 10.13.2.1291 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    FML{7.10.85.1291} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.2.1291.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forge{10.13.2.1291} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.2.1291.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    ssb{1.0} [Super Smash Bros mod] (bin) Unloaded->Errored
[22:56:55] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.client.Minecraft:displayCrashReport:398]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\David\Desktop\SuperSmashBrosMOd\eclipse.\crash-reports\crash-2015-02-07_22.56.55-client.txt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

Comment: Maybe there is more info in `C:\Users\David\Desktop\SuperSmashBrosMOd\eclipse.\crash-reports\crash-2015-02-07_22.56.55-client.txt`

Comment: and the code flatlined never mind